# mariadb service: Failed with result 'exit-code'

Tags: mariadb, raspberry

on my subject, there are several similar questions and answers, but all of them doesn't help

MariaDb installated on a Raspberry Pi was running now more than 3 years. Unfortunately I had a power-supply-break and after new start I had the problem with a not "clean" unmounted SSD (MySql-Data). I tried to solve the problem using by removing the directory "mysql-data" (rm .rf /mnt/myData/mysql-data) - this had worked in a previous case, but not now

maybe somebody can help me to findout a way?
thanks in advance
Max
[journal -xe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FNQn.png)

Comment: "all of them doesn't help" - did none of them mention NOT providing critical information via links? Not posting screenshots of text you can copy and paste? Checking the mysql error log?

Answer (score 0):

> I had the problem with a not "clean" unmounted SSD (MySql-Data)

The warning (not error) message I see in your screenshot is:

`Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because filesystem for /mnt/Phaselis_1/mysql-data is case insensitive`

Programs usually don't stop on warning messages so this one is a bit weird.

What filesystem is this? Please run `mount | grep /mnt/Phaselis_1/mysql-data` and paste the output here.

After a power outage it might make sense to run a `fsck.ext4 /dev/your-device-file`, provided your filesystem is ext4.

Please also provide the logs from `/var/log/syslog` or `journalctl` or `/var/log/mysql/*log`

> I tried to solve the problem using by removing the directory "mysql-data" (rm .rf /mnt/myData/mysql-data) - this had worked in a previous case, but not now.

`/mnt/myData/mysql-data` is not the same directory, or the same mount point, as `/mnt/Phaselis_1/mysql-data`. Are you talking about the same disk / device?

This sounds like you deleted all of the mysql data - is that correct? As in, you want to install mariadb-server from scratch and get rid of all the old data?